# How to count the number of iterations in a for comprehension in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, for-comprehension

I am using a for comprehension on a stream and I would like to know how many iterations took to get o the final results.

In code:

```
var count = 0
for {
   xs <- xs_generator
   x <- xs
   count = count + 1 //doesn't work!!
   if (x prop)
   yield x
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What is "prop"? Some predicate?

Comment: Yes, just to give the idea that I loop through a stream to build a new stream smaller in size and I would like to know how many elements I checked.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `.zipWithIndex`

Comment: @userunknown: Fixed, it was var .

Comment: @userunknown: Fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** If you don't want to return only the first item, but the entire stream of solutions, take a look at the second part.

**Edit-2:** Shorter version with `zipWithIndex` appended.

It's not entirely clear what you are attempting to do. To me it seems as if you are trying to find something in a stream of lists, and additionaly save the number of checked elements.

If this is what you want, consider doing something like this:

```
/** Returns `x` that satisfies predicate `prop` 
  * as well the the total number of tested `x`s
  */
def findTheX(): (Int, Int) = {
  val xs_generator = Stream.from(1).map(a => (1 to a).toList).take(1000)
  var count = 0
  def prop(x: Int): Boolean = x % 317 == 0
  for (xs <- xs_generator; x <- xs) {
    count += 1
    if (prop(x)) {
      return (x, count)
    }
  }
  throw new Exception("No solution exists")
}

println(findTheX())

// prints:
// (317,50403)
```

Several important points:

- Scala's for-comprehension have *nothing* to do with Python's "yield". Just in case you thought they did: re-read the documentation on for-comprehensions.
- There is no built-in syntax for breaking out of for-comprehensions. It's better to wrap it into a function, and then call `return`. There is also `breakable` though, but it works with Exceptions.
- The function returns the found item and the total count of checked items, therefore the return type is `(Int, Int)`.
- The error in the end after the `for`-comprehension is to ensure that the return type is `Nothing <: (Int, Int)` instead of `Unit`, which is not a subtype of `(Int, Int)`.
- Think twice when you want to use `Stream` for such purposes in this way: after generating the first few elements, the `Stream` holds them in memory. This might lead to "GC-overhead limit exceeded"-errors if the Stream isn't used properly.

Just to emphasize it again: the `yield` in Scala for-comprehensions is unrelated to Python's `yield`. Scala has no built-in support for coroutines and generators. You don't need them as often as you might think, but it requires some readjustment.

---

**EDIT**

I've re-read your question again. In case that you want an entire stream of solutions together with a counter of how many different `x`s have been checked, you might use something like that instead:

```
val xs_generator = Stream.from(1).map(a => (1 to a).toList)
var count = 0
def prop(x: Int): Boolean = x % 317 == 0
val xsWithCounter = for {
  xs <- xs_generator; 
  x <- xs
  _ = { count = count + 1 }
  if (prop(x))
} yield (x, count)

println(xsWithCounter.take(10).toList)

// prints:
// List(
//   (317,50403), (317,50721), (317,51040), (317,51360), (317,51681), 
//   (317,52003), (317,52326), (317,52650), (317,52975), (317,53301)
// )
```

Note the `_ = { ... }` part. There is a limited number of things that can occur in a `for`-comprehension:

- generators (the `x <-` things)
- filters/guards (`if`-s)
- value definitions

Here, we sort-of abuse the value-definition syntax to update the counter. We use the block `{ counter += 1 }` as the right hand side of the assignment. It returns `Unit`. Since we don't need the result of the block, we use `_` as the left hand side of the assignment. In this way, this block is executed once for every `x`.

**EDIT-2**

If mutating the counter is not your main goal, you can of course use the `zipWithIndex` directly:

```
val xsWithCounter = 
  xs_generator.flatten.zipWithIndex.filter{x => prop(x._1)}
```

It gives almost the same result as the previous version, but the indices are shifted by `-1` (it's the indices, not the number of tried `x`-s).

Comment: did you consider using `.zipWithIndex` here instead of a mutable counter?

Comment: @SethTisue I've added a `zipWithIndex`-version. And now that I notice that you aren't the OP, I don't know what to say, because otherwise I would advise you to just use the `zipWithIndex` version ;) . To be honest: no, I didn't consider `zipWithIndex`, because I was entirely focused on the task of writing it in the most awkward way using the mutable counter from OP's non-compiling code. If it was a piece of code that I write for myself, I'd probably use `zipWithIndex` without thinking about it. But yeah... We should of course try to promote best practices here, not mutable counters. ;) Thanks!